# Why can't I hide my br tag?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've added a `<br>` into my `h1` tag visible only on xl screens (>1600px).

The `<br>` however is showing all the time, when I want it to respond to the XL class (`visible-xl`).

**Live URL:** http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/

**CSS:**

```
@screen-xl:                  1600px;
@screen-xl-min:              @screen-xl;
@screen-xl-desktop:          @screen-xl-min;
@screen-lg-max:              (@screen-xl-min - 1);
@container-xl-desktop:       ((1560px + @grid-gutter-width));
@container-xl:               @container-large-desktop;

@media (min-width: @screen-xl-min) {
  .make-grid(xl);
}

.container {
  @media (min-width: @screen-xl-min) {
    width: @container-xl;
  }
}

.make-xl-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left:  (@gutter / 2);
  padding-right: (@gutter / 2);

  @media (min-width: @screen-xl-min) {
    float: left;
    width: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}

.make-xl-column-offset(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-xl-min) {
    margin-left: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}

.make-xl-column-push(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-xl-min) {
    left: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}

.make-xl-column-pull(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-xl-min) {
    right: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}

.visible-xl {
  .responsive-invisibility();
  @media (min-width: @screen-xl-min) {
    .responsive-visibility();
  }
}

.hidden-xl {
  @media (min-width: @screen-xl-min) {
    .responsive-invisibility();
  }
}

.make-grid-columns() {
  // Common styles for all sizes of grid columns, widths 1-12
  .col(@index) when (@index = 1) { // initial
    @item: ~".col-xs-@{index}, .col-sm-@{index}, .col-md-@{index}, .col-lg-@{index}, .col-xl-@{index}";
    .col((@index + 1), @item);
  }
  .col(@index, @list) when (@index =< @grid-columns) { // general; "=<" isn't a typo
    @item: ~".col-xs-@{index}, .col-sm-@{index}, .col-md-@{index}, .col-lg-@{index}, .col-xl-@{index}";
    .col((@index + 1), ~"@{list}, @{item}");
  }
  .col(@index, @list) when (@index > @grid-columns) { // terminal
    @{list} {
      position: relative;
      // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
      min-height: 1px;
      // Inner gutter via padding
      padding-left:  (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
      padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
    }
  }
  .col(1); // kickstart it
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h1 class="boldme hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-xl" id="homepage-headline">Wish you were taught personal finance at school?<br class="visible-xl"/>We do too</h1>
```

**Notes:**I'm using Bootstrap

Comment: two `h1` tags?! spider reads two even you make it hide!

Comment: There's only one <h1>.

Comment: no, open OP's link, you will see two h1, @Goombah

Comment: Looks like you're not hiding it on smaller screen.

Comment: Thanks all, I've now switched to one <h1> tag with a <br> visible only on XL (>1600px) screens. I've updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using two `<h1>` tags may be harmful for SEO purposes.
2. Both `<h1>` elements have the same `ID`, which is invalid markup; each ID in a document must be unique.

My solution:

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="boldme hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-xl" id="homepage-headline">Wish you were taught personal finance at school? We do too</h1> 
    <h1 class="boldme visible-xl" id="homepage-headline2">Wish you were taught personal finance at school?<br>We do too</h1> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.hidden-xs .hidden-sm {
    display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1600px) {
    .hidden-xs .hidden-sm {
        display: block;
    }

    .visible-xl {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

*Note: change your property or value as you want! and think about remove second `<h1>`*

Comment: "It's not valid" That's not true. It's perfectly valid to have multiple `<h1>` elements in a document.

Comment: Google looks at `h1` tags as clues to what the page's content is about. If you have multiple `h1` tags with different keywords then it is difficult for Google to contextualize the page. @TylerH , I not saying invalid in `html` i talking about `SEO` / and Also it's not valid in `html 4` only valid on `html 5` @TylerH

Comment: It's valid in HTML4, too. https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-H1 There's no mention of any restriction on the number of times you can use an `<h1>` element. That notion is purely fabricated by people trying to find some SEO magic solution, which itself is a largely opinion-based field.

Comment: I didn't see any mention, but I read it many time in other valid website. and also in this one [Link](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824) `Yes, it's true. You can now use as many sets of <h1> tags as are required, via HTML5. But that doesn't mean they should be freely added in arbitrary locations.`

Comment: External sites aren't qualified to say whether something can or cannot be done with a WG-defined language. When you're curious about whether something can be done, consult the specification; it's literally the rule book. As an example, see this article completely rebutting the article you just mentioned: http://adrianroselli.com/2013/12/the-truth-about-truth-about-multiple-h1.html

Comment: I think my solution to break my H1 tag on large screens via two H1 tags (one with the break and one without) and only one showing at one time, may not be the best course of action. R.E. SEO If I have two H1 tags using the exact same wording, this isn't going to move the SEO needle. High authority links however, will. The problem lies with the XL class I've created for some reason not being understood.

Comment: I've now switched to one <h1> tag with a <br> visible only on XL (>1600px) screens. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @SamJefferies I'm a little confused, I checked your website, you changed `h1` to `h2` and `h3` right? now what are you trying to do? hide which one in `1600px` ?

Comment: Please see my OP @pedram I've recently updated it. This should explain all.